# Get multiple inputs value Onchange Action - JQUERY

Tags: jquery, spring

How can we get multiple inputs value "onchange" action?
I need to calculate it and diplay results on another input at the same form..

here is my Code:

```
<f:input id="note1" path="infoformation.note1" />
<f:input id="note2" path="infoformation.note2" />
```

// where I should return results after sum the two values..

```
<f:input id="notetotal" path="infoformation.noteTotal" />
```

Comment: All are ok . what you tried in jquery?

Comment: I am beginner.. I know only how to get each value on seperated function..

Comment: post your html,js code

Comment: ok here is my html code..

Comment: can you please post your code.What you have been tried so far???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

Html

```
<input type="text" id="firstInputId" />
<input type="text" id="secondInputId" />
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input[type=text]").change(function(){
  $("#secondInputId").val($("#secondInputId").val()+","+$(this).val());
 });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amaj6/6/)

Comment: He have multiple input values .